# MongoDB $elemMatch on array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document like this :

```
{
  "values": 
    [
      ["a","231"],
      ["b","232"],
      ["c","233"],
      ["a","235"]  
    ]
}
```

How to use `$elemMatch` on value property. 
want to project elements in values that first element of them are "**a**".

something like this:

```
db.test.find({"values" : {$elemMatch: { "matchedElemet"[0]: "a"}}},{"values.$":1})
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
db.test.find(
    {
        'values': {
            $elemMatch: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    $in: ['a']
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "values.$": 1
    }
)
```

or

```
db.test.find(
    {},
    {
        'values': {
            $elemMatch: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    $in: ['a']
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

I hope I got your requirement correctly and this helps.

Comment: being first element of array is the point
if a is in second place in array i dont want to match that

Comment: @SajjadRahnama Can you do one thing on the application layer? first filter the first values only by using splice : db.test.find({},{'values':{$slice:1}}); and then use the above query. That should solve your problem till you find a single query

Comment: yes its better solution to do this in application layer